# Handlebars output null for missing fields

Tags: javascript, json, html-table, handlebars.js, missing-data

I am trying to use handlebars to format data received from a JSON file. My current structure is something similar to this:

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mark</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>School</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {{#each students}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ this.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ this.mark }}</td>
                <td>{{ this.subject }}</td>
                <td>{{ this.school }}</td>
                <td>{{ this.birthday }}</td>
           </tr>
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The JSON file I have does not have consistent structure, some student element only contains name (missing all other fields), and some only contain name and school.

If I am using my current code to template the JSON file, I will be getting a table with a lot of blank cells which I would like to write in "null" instead.

I was thinking maybe I should write a registerhelper but if so, how exactly should I do it?

Comment: It's also possible without any specific helper; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a handlebars helper as follows:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("getStudentValue", function(val) {
    if(val === undefined) {
        return "null";
    }
    return val;
});
```

And the corresponding markup would look like:

```
 {{#each students}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{getStudentValue this.name }}</td>
            <td>{{getStudentValue this.mark }}</td>
            <td>{{getStudentValue this.subject }}</td>
            <td>{{getStudentValue this.school }}</td>
            <td>{{getStudentValue this.birthday }}</td>
       </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 9):

Recent versions of Handlebars.js [support the following](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#blockHelperMissing) to report *all* missing helpers and values in things like `{{myName}}`, `{{something.myName}}` or `{{myHelper someValue}}`, without the need for a dummy helper within the curly braces:

```javascript
Handlebars.registerHelper('helperMissing', function(/* [args, ] options */) {
    var options = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    return 'MISSING VALUE: ' + options.name;
});
```

(Tested with 2.0.0)

And though the question is for JavaScript, for posterity here's a solution for  [Handlebars.java](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java):

```java
final Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();

/*
 * By default, Handlebars outputs an empty String for missing values,
 * and throws an exception if a helper is missing. Here, make it never
 * throw an exception, and show a warning in the result text.
 */
handlebars.registerHelperMissing(new Helper<Object>() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence apply(final Object context, final Options options) 
          throws IOException {
       return "MISSING VALUE: " + options.helperName;
    }
});
```

(Tested with the most recent version, being 1.3.2)

And the same for [Mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java):

```java
final DefaultMustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();

mf.setObjectHandler(new ReflectionObjectHandler() {
    @Override
    public Wrapper find(final String name, final Object[] scopes) {
        Wrapper wrapper = super.find(name, scopes);
        if (wrapper instanceof MissingWrapper) {
            return new Wrapper() {
                @Override
                public Object call(Object[] scopes) throws GuardException {
                    return "MISSING VALUE: " + name;
                }
            };
        }
        return wrapper;
    }
});
```

(Tested with version 0.8.2, which is a bit outdated. Not tested with conditionals and loops.)